# lamda is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Tags: c++, lambda

If i try to build my code, i get a error for this piece of code.

```
auto split = [&](auto component_selector, float plane) {
        int current_mid = start;
        uint32_t current_left = start;
        uint32_t current_right = end-1;
        aabb current_box_l, current_box_r;
        while (current_left < current_right) {
            while (component_selector(center(triangles[current_left])) <= plane && current_left < current_right) {
                current_left++;
                current_mid++;
            }
            while (component_selector(center(triangles[current_right])) > plane && current_left < current_right) {
                current_right--;
            }
            if(component_selector(center(triangles[current_left])) > component_selector(center(triangles[current_right])) && current_left < current_right) {
                std::swap(triangle_indices[current_left], triangle_indices[current_right]);
            }
        }
    };
```

The error says use of deleted function, with the note that it is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

```
error: use of deleted function ‘binary_bvh_tracer::subdivide_sah(std::vector<triangle>&, std::vector<vertex>&, uint32_t, uint32_t)::<lambda(auto:2, float)>::~<lambda>()’

Code block here

note: ‘binary_bvh_tracer::subdivide_sah(std::vector<triangle>&, std::vector<vertex>&, uint32_t, uint32_t)::<lambda(auto:2, float)>::~<lambda>()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  246 |  auto split = [&](auto component_selector, float plane) {
      |                 ^
```

I have no clue what causes the problem, would be glad to get some hints!

EDIT:

I changed the lambda from triangle vector data itself to use an array with indices on the vectordata. In the old version i can build and run without any errors. The git diff might help to spot the error because the old code build fine:

```
+       uint32_t triangle_indices[end];
+       for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
+               triangle_indices[i] = i;
+       }
        
        auto split = [&](auto component_selector, float plane) {
                int current_mid = start;
-               triangle* current_left = triangles.data() + start;
-               triangle* current_right = triangles.data() + end-1;
+               uint32_t current_left = start;
+               uint32_t current_right = end-1;
                aabb current_box_l, current_box_r;
                while (current_left < current_right) {
-                       while (component_selector(center(*current_left)) <= plane && current_left < current_right) {
+                       while (component_selector(center(triangles[triangle_indices[current_left]])) <= plane && current_left < current_right) {
                                current_left++;
                                current_mid++;
                        }
-                       while (component_selector(center(*current_right)) > plane && current_left < current_right) {
+                       while (component_selector(center(triangles[triangle_indices[current_right]])) > plane && current_left < current_right) {
                                current_right--;
                        }
-                       if(component_selector(center(*current_left)) > component_selector(center(*current_right)) && current_left < current_right) {
-                               std::swap(*current_left, *current_right);
+                       if(component_selector(center(triangles[triangle_indices[current_left]])) > component_selector(center(triangles[triangle_indices[current_right]])) && current_left < current_right) {
+                               std::swap(triangle_indices[current_left], triangle_indices[current_right]);
                        }
                }
```

Comment: It says the member function `~<lambda>()` of the lambda is implicitly deleted. That function is the destructor of the lambda. In the default definition, the destructor would just call all the destructors of all member objects. So that has to be ill-formed. At this point I am a bit stumped. First, this lambda captures nothing by value, just everything by reference, so there are no member objects. Secondly, even if there were member objects those would have to have a deleted destructor for this to occur and that seems weird. Can you provide a bit more code as context?

Comment: Is this the whole error message?

Comment: @n314159 Not quite sure which part of the code would help here, triangle_indices[] is initialized and filled before the lamda definition. The lamda calls are like this for x,y and z
`for (int i = 0; i < current_number_of_planes; ++i) {
   split([](const vec3 &v) { return v.x; }, box.min.x + (i+1)*(extent.x/(current_number_of_planes+1)));
  }`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no it's not the complete error message, i skipped the Part where the code comes up. I added it above.

Comment: @jk_ Ah okay. I expected there to be more `note:` messages at the end explaining why it's deleted, but no luck.

Comment: It's hard to help without having a [mcve]. If you have Clang installed, you could try building with it in hope for a better error message.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i totaly see that, thanks for the link btw. In this case it's pretty hard for me to boil the code down so it follows this example. I added the git diff from the working and not working versions, this might help.

Comment: Some tips for a minimal reproducible example: Try deleting everything inside the body of the lambda. If the error goes away, go back to the original and remove about half. If the error still goes away, remove the other half. Continue removing halves until removing anything else removes the error. Also work on the context. Start with the function that contains the definition of `split` and do the remove-halves trick to minimize that. See if you can remove enough noise so that the culprit cannot hide.